# No puedo convertir un String a un Booleano

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Estoy con un formulario, en C# con la estructura MVC, y no logro convertir el `string` a `bool`, se supone que el código a escribir se debe hacer desde controlador y en el html

```
<form>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TRABAJO)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TRABAJO)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TRABAJO)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ESTUDIANTE)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ESTUDIANTE)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ESTUDIANTE)
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Explícame como haces para convertir un `string` en un `boolean` creo que eso es imposible. Lo que si puedes hacer es evaluar un `string` y devolver un `boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

C# no permite la conversión implícita de cadena a booleano, ya que la variable booleana solo puede tener los valores **True o False** y el string puede tener millones de caracteres distintos.

Yo supongo que la cadena que deseas convertir a booleano contiene: "True" o "False", entonces, para evaluar si el string se puede convertir a booleano debes de utilizar el método estático tryParse implementado por todos los tipos de datos primitivos.

por ejemplo:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string miValorVerdero = "True";
            const string miValorFalso = "False";
            const string miNombre = "Juan";

            if (bool.TryParse(miValorVerdero, out var miVariableBooleana))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Se puede convertir miValorVerdero");
                Console.WriteLine($"el valor de miVariableBooleana es: {miVariableBooleana}");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NO Se pudo convertir miValorVerdero");
            }

            if (bool.TryParse(miValorFalso, out miVariableBooleana))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Se pudo convertir miValorFalso");
                Console.WriteLine($"el valor de miVariableBooleana: {miVariableBooleana}");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NO Se pudo convertir miValorFalso");
            }

            if (bool.TryParse(miNombre, out miVariableBooleana))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Se pudo convertir miNombre");
                Console.WriteLine($"el valor de miVariableBooleana: {miVariableBooleana}");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NO se pudo convertir miNombre");
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}

// Output:
// Se puede convertir miValorVerdero
// el valor de miVariableBooleana es: True
// Se pudo convertir miValorFalso
// el valor de miVariableBooleana: False
// NO se pudo convertir miNombre
```

También puedes desarrollar tu propio método que determine si una cadena se puede convertir a boolean siguiendo tus propias reglas. Ej.:

```
public static bool ConvertirStrBool(string cadena)
    {
        switch (cadena.ToLower())
        {
            case "true":
                return true;
            case "t":
                return true;
            case "1":
                return true;
            case "0":
                return false;
            case "false":
                return false;
            case "f":
                return false;
            default:
                throw new InvalidCastException("Este valor no se puede convertir a bool!");
        }
    }
```